# Mark GetStream activity as seen and read

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

I want to apply `mark_seen` and `mark_read` for a specific activity of `getstream.io`, but the counter is still the same. Here is my code:

```
const notification = client.feed('NOTIFICATION', '1');
notification.get({ mark_seen: ['1111111-f22d-333-33-0000001f'] }); //getstream activity id
```

**Update:**

Here is my get stream response:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "activities": [
                {
                    "actor": "user:1",
                    "foreign_id": "POST:50",
                    "id": "00000000-0000-11e0-8000-800001be0000",
                    "object": "POST:50",
                    "origin": null,
                    "target": "USER:1",
                    "time": "2018-01-12T14:08:03.000000",
                    "verb": "CREATE"
                }
            ],
            "activity_count": 1,
            "actor_count": 1,
            "created_at": "2018-01-12T14:08:12.324882",
            "group": "user:1_POST:50",
            "id": "111111bb-f1a1-11e1-1111-111111111b11.user:1_POST:50",
            "is_read": false,
            "is_seen": false,
            "updated_at": "2018-01-12T14:08:12.324882",
            "verb": "CREATE"
        }
    ],
    "next": "",
    "duration": "25.85ms",
    "unseen": 3,
    "unread": 3
}
```

I am using `activity.id` to mark my activity as read, but its not working.
However it works *(and decrements the counter)* when I use `id` *(the group id)*.

Comment: To clarify, are you referring to the counter in the response to the Feed.get() call? This would be intended behaviour. The counter should be decremented in subsequent calls to the API. It will help if you can share the sequence of API calls and the responses returned at each point (strip any sensitive data).

Comment: @DwightGunning please check my above question

Comment: The `mark_seen` array contains an ID (`1111111-f22d-333-33-0000001f`) that doesn't appear at all in the response. Are you sure that it's an ID of an activity in the feed?

Comment: i changed the ids which is not actual rest of the data is same

Comment: @DwightGunning I just checked, the `id` provided in the data (grouped id) works fine and marks `read` as well as `seen`. I wasn't using `group id` instead using single `activity id`.

Comment: Great. Best to describe the solution in an Answer and mark it accepted.